# how to calculate count(*) in various percentiles

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say, I have a table holding integer values from 0 up to 9,999 and I want to make a distribution plot of the population of values in each percentile.

Below is what comes to mind. Is there a better way?

```
CREATE TABLE A(x INTEGER);

SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=0  AND x<10) AS prcntl_01,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=10 AND x<20) AS prcntl_02,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=20 AND x<30) AS prcntl_03,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=30 AND x<40) AS prcntl_04,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=40 AND x<50) AS prcntl_05,
...
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE x>=990 AND x<1000) AS prcntl_100,
```

The size of the SQL statement is not a consideration as I can generate it on the fly. I am just wondering if there is an idiomatic way to get population counts in each percentile.

Comment: What do you mean by percentile? Each percentile should have the same number of rows (1/100 of observations) so I do not understand what are you trying to calculate here. Have a look at [ntile](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html). In 9.4 (devel) there are some [percentile functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead of multiple queries:

```
SELECT sum(case when x >= 0  AND x < 10 then 1 else 0 end) as prcntl_01,
       sum(case when x >= 10  AND x < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as prcntl_02,
       . . .
       sum(case when x >= 990  AND x < 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as prcntl_100
FROM A;
```

If you want the values in separate rows rather than columns, you can simply do:

```
select n as which,
       sum(case when x >= (n - 1)*10 and x < n*10 - 1 then 1 else 0 end) as percentile
from A cross join
     generate_series(1, 100) as n
group by n;
```

This limits the amount of code you have to write.

Comment: there must be a typo in the second form (comma after the percentile). Moreover, once that's removed PostgreSQL complains: ERROR: column "n.n" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function